# How to check if there is an instance of a singleton, and don't create a new one if not?

Tags: c++, singleton

I'd like to know how it is possible with c++ to check if there is an instance of any singleton object present during runtime. My current implementation of the getInstance() method looks like this:

```
singletonclass* getInstance() {
    if (pInstance == 0) {
       pInstance = new singletonclass();
    }
    return pInstance;
}
```

The problem is, that this implementation will create also a new instance if none is present. I'd like to only create an instance on one certain point of the code. On all other parts where i want to access the singleton object and none is present, it should throw an exception or something like this.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Just have a single call, "CreateInstance" in your program?

Comment: Yes, sure. But what happens if I want to access this instance and there is no object of it?

Comment: You can't have it both ways.  Either it's created when it's first requested, or you create it at one point and make sure you never try to access it before it's created.

Comment: _"The problem is, that this implementation will create also a new instance if none is present"_ Since when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag to fine tune the behavior:

```
singletonclass* getInstance(bool createIfNeeded = true) {
    if (pInstance == 0 )
    {
       if createIfNeeded )
       {
          pInstance = new singletonclass();
       }
       else
       {
          throw MyException();
       }
    }
    return pInstance;
}
```

Call `singletonclass::getInstance(false);` where appropriate.

Comment: What will happen if I try to call a method of this class like this:
`singletonclass::getInstance(false)->doSomething;` ?

Comment: You might run into undefined behavior.

Comment: It seems that this is my problem, I'd like to somehow catch this undefined behavior return something like an error code to the main application.